# Need help to deal with Photo for Xamarin forms

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am using xamarin forms. I want to pick photo from gallery for my iphone app and want to save it in Azure DB. Is there any solution available for xamarin  forms. Or Is there any plugin available to deal with Photo, Document, or Audio. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See this link https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Camera

Answer (score 1):

Using dependency service you can take or pick photos from Android / iPhone :-

Please refer to code below and try to implement the similar code:-
This is the interface in PCL:-

```
 public interface IGalleryProvider
    {
        Task<List<AttachmentMediaFile>> PickPhotoAsync();

        Task<List<AttachmentMediaFile>> PickAudioAsync();

        Task<List<AttachmentMediaFile>> PickDocumentAsync();

        Task<AttachmentMediaFile> PickProfilePhotoAsync();

        Task SaveToGalleryAsync(AttachmentMediaFile file);
    }
```

Below is the code using which you can pick or take photos from iPhone only:-

```
using AssetsLibrary;
using AVFoundation;
using ELCImagePicker;
using Foundation;
using MediaPlayer;
using MobileCoreServices;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UIKit;


[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(GalleryProvider))]

namespace SanketSample.MobileApp.Sample.iOS.Common
{
    public class GalleryProvider : IGalleryProvider
    {
        private TaskCompletionSource<List<AttachmentMediaFile>> _audioPickedTask;

        public async Task<List<AttachmentMediaFile>> PickAudioAsync()
        {
            _audioPickedTask = new TaskCompletionSource<List<AttachmentMediaFile>>();

            var picker = new MPMediaPickerController();

            ShowViewController(picker);

            picker.ItemsPicked += OnAudioPicked;
            picker.DidCancel += OnCancel;

            var media = await _audioPickedTask.Task;

            return media;
        }

        private void OnCancel(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var picker = sender as MPMediaPickerController;
            picker.DidCancel -= OnCancel;
            picker.DismissViewController(true, null);

            _audioPickedTask.TrySetResult(new List<AttachmentMediaFile>());
        }

        private void OnAudioPicked(object sender, ItemsPickedEventArgs e)
        {
            var media = new List<AttachmentMediaFile>();

            var picker = sender as MPMediaPickerController;
            picker.ItemsPicked -= OnAudioPicked;
            picker.DismissViewController(true, null);

            if (e.MediaItemCollection.Items != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.MediaItemCollection.Items)
                {
                 //var vm1 = (new ViewModelLocator()).AttachmentsVM.SelectedAttachments.Add();

                    if (!item.IsCloudItem)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            //var error = new NSError();
                            //var asset = new AVUrlAsset(item.AssetURL);
                            //var exporter = new AVAssetExportSession(asset, item.Title);
                            //exporter.OutputFileType = "com.apple.m4a-audio";
                            //AVAssetExportSession session = new AVAssetExportSession(asset, "");
                            //var reader = new AVAssetReader(asset, out error);
                            //var settings = new NSDictionary();
                            //Func<byte[]> bytesGetter = e.MediaItemCollection
                            //TODO item.Title, item.Title SSSanket,



                            //var _asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename(item.AssetURL.ToString()));
                            //var _exportSession = new AVAssetExportSession(_asset, AVAssetExportSession.PresetPassthrough);
                            //_exportSession.OutputFileType = AVFileType.Aiff;






                           // media.Add(new AttachmentMediaFile(item.AssetURL.AbsoluteString, AttachmentMediaFileType.Audio, null , item.Title));



                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            // throw ;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            _audioPickedTask.TrySetResult(media);
        }

        public async Task<List<AttachmentMediaFile>> PickDocumentAsync()
        {
            var task = new TaskCompletionSource<List<AttachmentMediaFile>>();

            var allowedUTIs = new string[]
                {
                    UTType.UTF8PlainText,
                    UTType.PlainText,
                    UTType.RTF,
                    UTType.Text,
                    UTType.PDF,
                    "com.microsoft.word.doc",
                    "com.microsoft.excel.xls"
                };

            var pickerMenu = new UIDocumentMenuViewController(allowedUTIs, UIDocumentPickerMode.Open);
            pickerMenu.DidPickDocumentPicker += (sender, args) =>
            {
                args.DocumentPicker.DidPickDocument += (sndr, pArgs) =>
                {
                    var securityEnabled = pArgs.Url.StartAccessingSecurityScopedResource();

                    NSError err;
                    var fileCoordinator = new NSFileCoordinator();
                    var docs = new List<AttachmentMediaFile>();

                    // Read bytes.
                    fileCoordinator.CoordinateRead(pArgs.Url, 0, out err, (NSUrl newUrl) =>
                    {
                        NSData data = NSData.FromUrl(newUrl);
                        docs.Add(new AttachmentMediaFile(pArgs.Url.AbsoluteString, AttachmentMediaFileType.Doc, data.ToArray(),null));
                        task.TrySetResult(docs);
                    });
                };

                ShowViewController(args.DocumentPicker);
            };

            ShowViewController(pickerMenu);

            return await task.Task;
        }

        public async Task<List<AttachmentMediaFile>> PickPhotoAsync()
        {
            var media = new List<AttachmentMediaFile>();
            var picker = ELCImagePickerViewController.Instance;
            picker.MaximumImagesCount = 15;

            ShowViewController(picker);

            await picker.Completion.ContinueWith(result =>
            {
                picker.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    picker.DismissViewController(true, null);

                    if (!result.IsCanceled && result.Exception == null)
                    {
                        var imageEditor = new ImageEditor();
                        var items = result.Result as List<AssetResult>;
                        foreach (var item in items)
                        {

                                var bbytes= imageEditor.ResizeImage(item.Image, 1024, 1024);


                            media.Add(new AttachmentMediaFile(item.Path, AttachmentMediaFileType.Photo, bbytes, item.Name));
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            return media;
        }

        public async Task<AttachmentMediaFile> PickProfilePhotoAsync()
        {
            AttachmentMediaFile selectMediaFile = null;
            var picker = ELCImagePickerViewController.Instance;
            picker.MaximumImagesCount = 1;
            ShowViewController(picker);

            await picker.Completion.ContinueWith(result =>
            {
                picker.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    picker.DismissViewController(true, null);

                    if (!result.IsCanceled && result.Exception == null)
                    {
                        var imageEditor = new ImageEditor();
                        var items = result.Result as List<AssetResult>;
                        foreach (var item in items)
                        {
                            var bbytes = imageEditor.ResizeImage(item.Image, 1024, 1024);

                            selectMediaFile = new AttachmentMediaFile(item.Path, AttachmentMediaFileType.Photo, bbytes, item.Name);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            return selectMediaFile;
        }

        public async Task SaveToGalleryAsync(AttachmentMediaFile file)
        {
            var bytes = file.GetBytes();
            var originalImage = ImageEditor.ImageFromByteArray(bytes);

            var library = new ALAssetsLibrary();
            var orientation = (ALAssetOrientation)originalImage.Orientation;
            var nsUrl = await library.WriteImageToSavedPhotosAlbumAsync(originalImage.CGImage, orientation);
        }

        private void ShowViewController(UIViewController controller)
        {
            var topController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
            while (topController.PresentedViewController != null)
            {
                topController = topController.PresentedViewController;
            }

            topController.PresentViewController(controller, true, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Below are useful classes :-

```
 public class AttachmentMediaFile
{
    private readonly Func<byte[]> _bytesGetter;

    public string LocalPath { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public AttachmentMediaFileType Type { get; private set; }

    public AttachmentMediaFile(string localPath, AttachmentMediaFileType type, byte[] bytesGetter, string name = null)
    {
        LocalPath = localPath;
        Type = type;
        _bytesGetter = () =>
        {
            return bytesGetter;
        };

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            Name = FileNameHelper.PrepareName(localPath);
        }
        else
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }

    public byte[] GetBytes()
    {
        return _bytesGetter();
    }
}

public enum AttachmentMediaFileType
{
    Photo = 0,
    Audio = 1,
    Doc = 2,
    Video = 3, 
}

public static class FileNameHelper
{
    private const string Prefix = "IMG";

    public static string PrepareName(string localPath)
    {
        var name = string.Empty;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(localPath))
        {
            name = localPath.Split('/').Last();
        }

        return name;
    }

    public static string GenerateUniqueFileName(Extension extension)
    {
        var format = ".jpg";

        var fileName = string.Concat(Prefix, '_', DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks, format);

        return fileName;
    }

    public enum Extension
    {
        JPG
    }
}
```

Now if you want to store your data to Azure Server Table so you are already using Azure mobile service client SDK similarly you need Blob nuget from Azure using which you can save your photos by making blob objects to Azure server :-

use blob helper nuget from manage nuget package install Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
this and try to implement the code similarly I given bellow:-

```
using Acr.UserDialogs;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SanketSample.MobileApp.sample.Business.Azure;
using SanketSample.MobileApp.sample.Business.Interfaces;
using SanketSample.MobileApp.sample.Models;
using SanketSample.MobileApp.sample.Models.AzureTables;
using SanketSample.MobileApp.sample.Models.Media;
using SanketSample.MobileApp.sample.Utils;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SanketSample.MobileApp.Sanket.Common.Media
{
    public class BlobHelper
    {

        private const string ContainerName = "attachments";
        private Dictionary<string, TaskCompletionSource<bool>> _tasks;
        private IHttpService _httpservice { get; set; }

        #region Singleton Implementation

        private static readonly Lazy<BlobHelper> lazyInstance = new Lazy<BlobHelper>(() => new BlobHelper(), true);


        private BlobHelper()
        {
            _tasks = new Dictionary<string, TaskCompletionSource<bool>>();
        }

        public static BlobHelper Instance
        {
            get { return lazyInstance.Value; }`enter code here`
        }

        #endregion Singleton Implementation

        public async Task UploadAttachments(IList<AttachmentFile> attachments, long associatedRecordId, string category)
        {
            foreach (var attachment in attachments)
            {
                await UploadAttachment(attachment, associatedRecordId, category);
            }
        }

        public async Task UploadAttachment(AttachmentFile attachment, long associatedRecordId, string category)
        {
            try
            {
                CommonHelper commonHelper = new CommonHelper();
                attachment.ContainerName = ContainerName;
                attachment.AssociatedRecordId = associatedRecordId;
                //attachment.RecordId = commonHelper.GenerateRecordId();
                if (attachment.FileExtension == null)
                {
                    attachment.FileExtension = ConvertType(attachment.MediaFile);
                }

                attachment.Category = category;
                var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

                if (!_tasks.ContainsKey(attachment.Name))
                { _tasks.Add(attachment.Name, taskCompletionSource); }
                else
                {
                    _tasks[attachment.Name] = taskCompletionSource;

                }

              //  _tasks.Add(attachment.Name, taskCompletionSource);
                var attachmentsTableOnline = AzureServiceProvider.Instance.GetRemoteTable<AttachmentFile>();
                if (CheckInternetConnection.IsConnected())
                {
                    await attachmentsTableOnline.InsertAsync(attachment);
                }
                var attachmentsTableOffline = AzureServiceProvider.Instance.GetLocalTable<AttachmentFile>();
                await attachmentsTableOffline.InsertAsync(attachment);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attachment.SasQueryString))
                {
                    var credentials = new StorageCredentials(attachment.SasQueryString);
                    var imageUri = new Uri(attachment.Uri);

                    var container = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}/{1}",
                        imageUri.Host, attachment.ContainerName)), credentials);

                    var blobFromSASCredential = container.GetBlockBlobReference(attachment.Name);
                    try
                    {
                        var bytes = attachment.MediaFile.GetBytes();
                        await blobFromSASCredential.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        if (CheckInternetConnection.IsConnected())
                        {
                            await attachmentsTableOnline.UpdateAsync(attachment);
                        }
                        await attachmentsTableOffline.UpdateAsync(attachment);
                        taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(true);
                    }
                    catch (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException ex)
                    {
                        // Throws from UploadFromByteArrayAsync, but image uploaded.
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"BlobHelper: {ex}");
                        taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(true);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"BlobHelper: {ex}");
                        taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(false);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ca)
            {
                //throw ca;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Downloads Blob Data boject and returns the Byts[] data
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="file"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task<byte[]> DownloadAttachment(AttachmentFile file)
        {
            byte[] bytes = null;
            var fileContainer = file.Uri.Replace(file.Name, string.Empty);

            var container = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(fileContainer));
            var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(file.Name);
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var isExist = await blob.ExistsAsync();
                if (isExist)
                {
                    await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);
                    bytes = stream.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return bytes;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Updates the Attachments Byts in the Azure Local Tables.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="AttachmentFileRecordId">Attachments Byte[] Data.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>

        public async Task<byte[]> DownloadAttachmentFileDetails(long? AttachmentFileRecordId, IHttpService service)
        {
            _httpservice = service;
            try
            {
                ResponseWrapper<AttachmentFileDetail> result = new ResponseWrapper<AttachmentFileDetail>();
                if (AttachmentFileRecordId != null)
                {

                    var request = Constants.API_BASE_URL + string.Format(Constants.API_ATTACHMENTS_PARAMETERS, AttachmentFileRecordId);
                    var response = await _httpservice.SendRequestAsync(HttpMethod.Get, request);
                    result.Status = response.Status;

                    if (response.IsSuccess)
                    {
                        result.Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AttachmentFileDetail>(response.Result);

                        if (result.Result == null)
                        {
                            result.Status = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var output = result.Result;
                            var data = new List<AttachmentFileDetail>() { output };
                            await AzureServiceProvider.Instance.DatabaseService.InsertDataToLocalDB<AttachmentFileDetail>(data);
                            return result.Result.FileByteArray;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ////throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
            }

            return null;

        }

        private string ConvertType(AttachmentMediaFile file)
        {
            switch (file.Type)
            {
                case AttachmentMediaFileType.Doc:
                    return "doc";

                case AttachmentMediaFileType.Audio:
                    return "mp3";
            }

            return "jpeg";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

media plugin on [github](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin)

works pretty well for me.